# What differences are expected of XHTML5 versus HTML5?

Tags: accessibility, standards, html

What differences are expected of XHTML5 versus HTML5?  I understand that XHTML5 is the XML form of the language and HTML5 is the SGML form of the language, which means obvious minor syntax differences.  Will there be any further differences?  Will XHTML5 deprecate completely worthless elements that were not deprecated by HTML5?  Will XHTML5 be written in schema instead of doctype?  Will XHTML5 impose structural validations instead of merely stating what is a child of what?  Will XHTML5 offer accessibility advantages that not available in HTML5?  Will XHTML5 offer any security enhancements?

Please share any knowledge you have about is claimed to be the future of the web?

Comment: What happened to xhtml 2 to 4?

Comment: @Giovanni - The numbering was a matter of some dispute back in 2007, and some people wanted XHTML5 called XHTML 1.5 instead, since they saw it as more evolutionary than the revolutionary proposals of XHTML 2. However, it was felt that it would be simpler to bring the numbering of HTML and XHTML into line with one another. XHTML 2 was recently shelved as the W3C thought that developing two versions of XHTML simultaneously was sending out a confusing message

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML is an attempt to document the differences between HTML5 and XHTML5. As far as I know it is the best available resource on this subject to date.

Answer (score 32):

> What differences are expected of XHTML5 versus HTML5?

The HTML5 "doctype" is not used. The xmlns attribute is required.

> I understand that XHTML5 is the XML form of
>   the language and HTML5 is the SGML form of the language

No. HTML5 is not SGML based.

> , which means obvious minor syntax differences.

No. Just some forms of syntax become forbidden.

> Will XHTML5 deprecate completely worthless elements that were not deprecated by HTML5?

No. They are just different serialisations.

> Will XHTML5 be written in schema instead of doctype?

There are, as far as I'm aware, no plans to have an official schema (or DTD for that matter: the doctype is "A thing to trigger standards mode in browsers" and nothing more).

> Will XHTML5 impose structural validations instead of merely stating what is a child of 
>   what?

No differences from HTML5.

> Will XHTML5 offer accessibility advantages that not available in HTML5?

No.

> Will XHTML5 offer any security enhancements?

No.

Comment: XHTML is going the way of the dinosaurs …

Comment: HTML5 is also an SGML grammar.  I have seen these two factual errors numerous times.  I can prove I correct by your inability to tell me which language HTML5 is written in.  Since you are factually in error I have given you a down vote.

Comment: @austin - HTML5 is written in English! No really. In the HTML5 draft, section 2.2 describes the HTML syntax as a custom format *inspired* by SGML. However, there are a number of features of HTML5 that cannot be described by an SGML DTD (this was also true of HTML4 actually) and no attempt has been made to ensure that the HTML5 rules comply with SGML.

Comment: “The HTML5 ‘doctype’ is not used.” Actually, the DOCTYPE is *optional* in XHTML5 (nuance, but still). However, if you want to use it, it must be written with ‘DOCTYPE’ in uppercase: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. More info here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhtml5