# Parse XHTML5 with undefined entities

Tags: python, xml, html, xhtml, lxml

Please consider this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xhtml = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head><title>XHTML sample</title></head>
            <body>
                <p>&nbsp;Sample text</p>
            </body>
        </html>
'''
parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.entity['nbsp'] = '&#x00A0;'
tree = ET.fromstring(xhtml, parser=parser)
print(ET.tostring(tree, method='xml'))
```

which renders nice text representation of `xhtml` string.

But, for same XHTML document with HTML5 doctype:

```
xhtml = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head><title>XHTML sample</title></head>
            <body>
                <p>&nbsp;Sample text</p>
            </body>
        </html>
'''
```

I get Exception:

`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity: line 5, column 19`

so the parser can't handle it, although I added `nbsp` to entities dict.

Same happens if I use `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
tree = etree.fromstring(xhtml, parser=parser)
print etree.tostring(tree, method='xml')
```

raises:

`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'nbsp' not defined, line 5, column 26`

although I've set the parser to ignore entities.

Why is this, and how to make parsing of XHTML files with HTML5 doctype declaration possible?

---

Partial solution for lxml is to use recoverer:

`parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, recover=True)`

but I'm still waiting for better one.

Comment: Try using `lxml.html.soupparser` instead.

Comment: I want to parse xml tree

Comment: For parsing HTML I can only recommend using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: The problem is, XML doesn't have `&nbsp;`, `&nbsp` is a HTML thing, *not* XML. Parsing HTML as as XML requires the use of XHTML5 (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415394/what-differences-are-expected-of-xhtml5-versus-html5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is, the [Expat parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html) used behind the scenes won't usually report unknown entities - it will rather throw an error, so the fallback code in `xml.etree.ElementTree` you were trying to trigger won't even run. You can use the [`UseForeignDTD` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.xmlparser.UseForeignDTD) to change this behavior, it will make Expat ignore the doctype declaration and pass all entity declarations to `xml.etree.ElementTree`. The following code works correctly:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xhtml = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head><title>XHTML sample</title></head>
            <body>
                <p>&nbsp;Sample text</p>
            </body>
        </html>
'''
parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser._parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity['nbsp'] = u'\u00A0'
tree = ET.fromstring(xhtml, parser=parser)
print(ET.tostring(tree, method='xml'))
```

The side-effect of this approach: as I said, the doctype declaration is completely ignored. This means that you have to declare **all** entities, even the ones supposedly covered by the doctype.

Note that the values you put into `ElementTree.XMLParser.entity` dictionary have to be regular strings, text that the entity will be replaced by - you can no longer refer to other entities there. So it should be `u'\u00A0'` for `&nbsp;`.